# Issue with textarea overflow:visible

Tags: css

i have a form with textareas like this:

```
<TEXTAREA NAME="tekniku_mesazh" id='tekniku_mesazh' COLS=40 ><pre><?php echo $row['tekniku_mesazh'];?></TEXTAREA>
```

Now, what i need to do is, i want the text to be visible inside it, 
i've tried:

```css
textarea {
    overflow:visible;
}
```

But this won't work, why is that?
Thanks

Comment: Does this text render inside? Maybe you have to change font color? Or check if this php script loads the text?

Comment: You're missing an ending `</pre>` tag. After the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problems:

1) If your $row['tekniku_mesazh'] string has html special chars, that may hide the text.
escape them:

```
<TEXTAREA NAME="tekniku_mesazh" id='tekniku_mesazh' COLS=40 ><pre><?php echo htmlentities($row['tekniku_mesazh']);?></TEXTAREA>
```

2) The "pre" tag is not closed, that will not hide the content, but it's a mistake also:

```
<TEXTAREA NAME="tekniku_mesazh" id='tekniku_mesazh' COLS=40 ><pre><?php echo htmlentities($row['tekniku_mesazh']);?></pre></TEXTAREA>
```

3) It's only a small/perfectionist mistake: use lowercase for tags:

```
<textarea name="tekniku_mesazh" id='tekniku_mesazh' cols=40 ><pre><?php echo htmlentities($row['tekniku_mesazh']);?></pre></textarea>
```

You may also simplify the php by using the shorter sintax (but that is not a mistake):

```
<textarea name="tekniku_mesazh" id='tekniku_mesazh' cols=40 ><pre><?=htmlentities($row['tekniku_mesazh'])?></pre></textarea>
```

I hope it help you.

Best regards, Adrian M.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
My issue is, if i put this, all i get inside the textarea is <pre> </pre>

Comment: Hum, it look like your row['tekniku_mesazh'] is empty, try to echo the content:
<?php var_dump($row['tekniku_mesazh']); ?>

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `<pre>` and first you have to check if actually rows[] cointains something

so and the top of the script you should write

```
var_dump($row); // Just for Debugging

<textarea name="tekniku_mesazh" id='tekniku_mesazh' cols=40 ><pre><?php echo $row['tekniku_mesazh'];?></pre></textarea>
```

also you can use the id for the css

```
#tekniku_mesazh {
    overflow:visible;
}
```

ps: you should a simple name for css :)